# Keep unique values in solution pool Cplex

Tags: cplex

In my consolidation problem, I am using solution pools to find all feasible, non-linear solutions. However, my output shows a lot of repetitions due to the different times periods and unlimited capacity of trucks when consolidation is possible. Here is my .mod file:

```
t sol2 = <total_cost, exp_fixed_cost_total, exp_fixed_cost_g_total, exp_fixed_cost_h_total, exp_cons_cost_total, exp_penalty_cost_total, exp_emission_cost_total, exp_emission_cost_g_total, exp_emission_cost_h_total>; //All costs for each feasible alternative

execute {
writeln("Total cost = ", total_cost);
writeln("Total expected fixed costs = ", exp_fixed_cost_total);
writeln("Total expected fixed non-consolidated costs = ", exp_fixed_cost_g_total);
writeln("Total expected fixed consolidated costs = ", exp_fixed_cost_h_total);
writeln("Total expected consolidation costs = ", exp_cons_cost_total);
writeln("Total expected penalty costs = ", exp_penalty_cost_total);
writeln("Total expected emission costs = ", exp_emission_cost_total);
writeln("Total expected emission non-consolidated costs = ", exp_emission_cost_g_total);
writeln("Total expected emission consolidated costs = ", exp_emission_cost_h_total);
writeln();}  

main {var outputfile=new IloOplOutputFile("sols2.dat");
outputfile.writeln("sols2={");
 
cplex.solnpoolintensity = 3;

thisOplModel.generate();
cplex.solve();
if (cplex.populate()) {
  var nsolns = cplex.solnPoolNsolns;
  
  writeln("Number of solutions found = ", nsolns);
  writeln();
  for (var s=0; s<nsolns; s++) {
    thisOplModel.setPoolSolution(s);
    thisOplModel.postProcess();
    outputfile.writeln(thisOplModel.sol2,",");
    }
}
outputfile.writeln("};");
outputfile.close();
```

}

The output looks like this in a .dat file: (not every output)

```
<2274 1200 975 225 54 20 1000 850 150>,
<2274 1200 975 225 54 20 1000 850 150>,
<2274 1200 975 225 54 20 1000 850 150>,
<2274 1200 975 225 54 20 1000 850 150>,
......
```

As you can see, I get a lot of repetitions. If I change the intensity to = 2, I don't generate enough values. Is there a way to specify that I only want to return the unique rows while keeping the intensity = 3? I was thinking about the replacement filter, but I am having a hard time to understand this command. Do I need to use this in combination with the solution pool capacity command?

Thank you so much for your help!
Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in cplex documentation,

> If the solutions you obtain are too similar to each other, try setting
> SolnPoolReplace to 2.

what you could also try is : rely on your own flow control without solution pools.

Example in https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooenumeratewithoutsolutionpool.mod

```
int nbiter=5;
range iter=1..nbiter;

int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;

dvar int+ nbBus40;
dvar int+ nbBus30;

// Not to get again those previous solutions
dvar int nbBus40prevSol[1..nbiter];
dvar int nbBus30prevSol[1..nbiter];
 
minimize
 costBus40*nbBus40^2  +nbBus30^2*costBus30;
 
subject to
{
 40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
 
 forall(i in iter) (nbBus40!=nbBus40prevSol[i]) || (nbBus30!=nbBus30prevSol[i]);
} 

execute
{
  writeln(nbBus40," buses 40 seats and ",nbBus30," buses 30 seats");
  writeln("cost : ",cplex.getObjValue());
}

main
{
  thisOplModel.generate();
  for(var i in thisOplModel.iter)
  {
    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();
    var sol40=thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue;
    var sol30=thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue;
    thisOplModel.nbBus40prevSol[i].UB=sol40;
    thisOplModel.nbBus40prevSol[i].LB=sol40;
    thisOplModel.nbBus30prevSol[i].UB=sol30;
    thisOplModel.nbBus30prevSol[i].LB=sol30;
    
  }
  
  
  1;
}

/*
which gives
4 buses 40 seats and 5 buses 30 seats
cost : 18000
5 buses 40 seats and 4 buses 30 seats
cost : 18900
3 buses 40 seats and 6 buses 30 seats
cost : 18900
6 buses 40 seats and 2 buses 30 seats
cost : 19600
6 buses 40 seats and 3 buses 30 seats
cost : 21600
*/
```

Comment: Thank you very much Alex! Your help is really appreciated. Concerning your own flow control without solution pools, is it correct that I cannot generate `forall(i in iter) (nbBus40!=nbBus40prevSol[i]) || (nbBus30!=nbBus30prevSol[I]);` when nbBus40 and nbBus40prevSol are declared as floats instead of integers?